# iPhone keeps restarting: How to identify the (probable) offending app?

Tags: iphone, crash

So my iPhone keeps rebooting after working seemingly normally for some time, albeit quite a short one - I'd say around 10 minutes, seems to be quite shorter if I'm using it, no matter the app.

It started doing it today, apparently out of nowhere. I tried scrolling the Privacy → Analytics section under the Settings app, but didn't find anything obvious. I noticed some (*many*) `panic-full-<datetime>.ips` files with what seems to be a memory and diagnostic dump from the incidents, but again they don't seem to show anything obvious.

Is there any way of identifying the offending piece of software?

It's an iPhone XS, and it has been on the latest iOS (12.2 I think) since its release, so it's been a while now.

Comment: A possible explanation could be a faulty hardware component. It's advisable to get it diagnosed by authorized service provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A phone does not and should not reboot just because of some misbehaving app. The problem you have occurs due to issues on a lower level, such as battery or memory fault.

You don't have any means to determine and fix those issues, so just hand it over to a repair shop.

Comment: I guess both you and @Nimesh Neema are right: I restored iOS and it kept doing it, so now I'm setting up a replacement with Apple :/